# How do I position two JButtons at PAGE_END with BorderLayout without them overlapping?

Tags: java, swing, positioning, jbutton, border-layout

So I want the button `Select` to be above button `Back` and I don't want them overlapping each other. But when I set them both the `PAGE_END`, they overlap. How do I get around this?

Here is the code for the problem:

```
public void methodName() {
    JPanel controls = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5,5));
    final CardLayout cl = new CardLayout();
    final JPanel panel = new JPanel(cl);
    controls.add(panel);
    this.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));        
    list = new JList<Object>(objectName);
        list.setVisibleRowCount(7);
        select = new JButton("Select");
        back = new JButton("Back");
        select.addActionListener(this);
        controls.add(new JScrollPane(list));
        controls.add(select, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        controls.add(back, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        controls.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(25,25,0,0));
        add(controls);
        refreshFrame();
}
```

Here is what it looks like when they are both added in but are overlapping:

[image: The problem (Overlapping)]

This is what I want it to look like:

[image: This is what it should look like]

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place the 2 `JButtons` on a new `JPanel` using `GridLayout` like this

```
JPanel basePanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, 3));
basePanel.add(select);
basePanel.add(back);
controls.add(basePanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
```

`GridLayout` can provide a vertical gap between buttons in its [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/GridLayout.html#GridLayout%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) as shown in your question

Comment: Use this instead of the `BorderLayout`?

Answer (score 2):

create a new jpanel with gridLayout(2,1) then add the two buttons to the jpanel then add the Jpanel to the Jframe